# How to give conditions in a scatter plot in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Only the below condition should reflect in the scatter plot.How can i plot the condition?

```
ipl.player[imdb.player< 0]


ax.scatter(data=ipl,x='player',y='budget')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is extremely confusing and unclear because you have two dataframes, IIUC, you want something like this

```
ax.scatter(data=ipl[ipl.player< 0], x='player', y='budget')
```

Comment: That was a typo! Thanks